# explanation of Java properties

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

What does it the below code mean ?

```
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.apache.openejb.client.RemoteInitialContextFactory");
    p.put("java.naming.provider.url", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/tomee/ejb");
```

What does the last line java.naming.provider.url do ? Is it reffering to the EJB container path where my bean EAR file is located ?

Thanks
Senthil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code `p.put("java.naming.provider.url", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/tomee/ejb");` is the location where your JNDI service is running.

***"java.naming.provider.url"*** is the name of the property for specifying the location of the JNDI service provider that your client will use. More simply put, it is a URL that tells you where the data store is.